# Convert String variable to SSIS object variable

Tags: c#, ssis

I have no clue where to start with this.  What I am asking is if this is possible.

I know that I can read an SSIS object, break it down and load it to a string.  But can I do the reverse?

I don't need an example or s working script to do it, but a piece or some document of a method to look at would be great.  Or a simple yes/no would even be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. The SSIS `Object` variable is just like a regular `System.Object`:

```
public void f()
{
    Dts.Variables["MyObjectVar"].Value = "Hello";
}

//inside another script task
public void g()
{
    object myObjectVar = Dts.Variables["MyObjectVar"].Value;
    string myString = (string)myObjectVar;
    //myString will contain "Hello" if f() is executed before g()
}
```

Obviously there is no need to store strings in SSIS object variables (because you can declare a SSIS variable of `String` type). But you can store instances of any user-defined type inside SSIS objects. That may be handy if you need to pass some complicated data between your script tasks and such.

Comment: With this in mind, I could parse out say a string that has data separated by a special character.  The goal would be to loop for each entry in the Object.

Comment: @eddiecubed Yes, you can create, for example, an array of strings and store it in a SSIS object variable.

Answer (score 0):

don't use foreach, use for and the functions TOKEN and TOKENCOUNT

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).